# Программа для генерации тестов

Tags: поиск-программ

Есть ли программы для генерации тестов? Например, возьмём физику. Допустим, у нас есть набор вопросов с ответами, разделённый по категориям: механика, электричество, молекулярка и т.д. Пусть по 50-100 вопросов в каждом. Есть ли программа, которая позволяла бы генерировать тесты путём выборки, например, 20 вопросов из разных разделов или из отдельно взятого. В идеале, чтобы сразу генерировалась форма тестирования, и тест уже можно было бы проходить в формате чекбоксов или в формате "вбей ответ", и получить в итоге результат с количеством правильных ответов.

Поисковики выдают indigo и adtester. Был бы рад, если кто-то, кто занимался тестами, порекомендует программы или подскажет в каком направлении копать тему. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Не знаю, можно ли задавать такой вопрос тут. Если нет, извините.